# Why are so many hats named after numbers? What do the numbers mean?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

The names for Winter Bash hats are often puns or refer to something. This year, several of the hats are named as some number, which is a little more opaque. Why are numbers so popular this year?  What do they refer to for each hat?

Here are the number-named hats for reference:

### Secret hats:

#### 180°

[image]

> Presumably a 180-degree turn / U-turn

---

#### 8,243,721

[image]

---

#### 6

[image]

---

### Regular hats:

#### 011

collect 11 hats

[image]

> Presumably the "11" is for collecting 11 hats, but why the leading "0"?

---

#### 925

earn a silver badge

[image]

---

#### 24

earn a gold badge

[image]

> Presumably 24-carat (pure) gold

Comment: 925 is the percentage of silver in sterling silver... 92.5%. The Ernie and Bert ones are their respective favorite numbers.

Comment: @Catija, make it an answer. I'll upvote it. Bert & Ernie have favorite numbers?

Comment: Oh my goodness it's Bert and Ernie!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: That question came after this, & states that the hats named after numbers had already been addressed here. So it is for the remaining hats.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are many reasons for the names of the hats. I can give a bit of background on why/how I picked some of the names.

The theme of numbers started with the naming for the silver and gold badge hats. Various ideas were tossed around, until I settled on the names **24** and **925**. The 24 was for [24 karat gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold), and 925 is for the stamp that is typically on [sterling silver = .925](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_silver).

Once I had two hats with numbers, I decided to just continue the theme for several others.

I wanted a pair of characters for hats and somehow happened upon Bert & Ernie from Sesame Street. Once I found them, I discovered [their favorite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bert_(Sesame_Street)) and the **6** & **8,243,721** hats were created.

> Bert's favorite number is **6** ... Ernie's whose favorite number is **8,243,721**

The **180° hat** is a secret hat so I won't fully disclose the reason for picking the number, but it might have something to do with actions on the site.

Finally, **011** was chosen because you get the hat when you get 11 hats.  This was named after [Eleven on Stranger Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleven_(Stranger_Things)) who happens to have a tattoo with '011', so it fit perfectly. The character also loves waffles, and wears a pink shirt with a blue jacket.

It wasn't my intention to have so many hats with numbers, but once it started I just ran with it.

Comment: And that's why it's a waffle... because she loved waffles. It all becomes clear.

Comment: Exactly @Catija. Notice the pink shirt and blue jacket as well.

Comment: `011` is mis-named.  A leading "0" indicates octal notation, and people with octal 11 hats are going to be quite disappointed not to have it awarded to them.

Comment: The reference comes from Stranger Things @Mark. She didn't know her name and they called her Eleven because of the 011 tattoo.

Comment: While we are at it: *180°* should have been named *π.* It’s more obfuscating (which becomes a secret hat) and who uses degrees anyway?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft maybe next year.

Comment: 180 degree turn *cough cough* reversal *cough cough* unicorns

Comment: Ironically, as soon as you get 11 hats, you immediately get your twelfth: "**011**".

Comment: @Mark I guess that Eleven is really Nine, then.

Answer (score 12):

All of the numbers relate to the badge.

#### [Silver and gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fineness) -

24 relates to 24 karat, or pure gold, though it's technically only 99.9% pure.

925 is a number inherent to sterling silver. Like 24 karat, 92.5% is the pureness of sterling silver.

> Sterling silver contains 92.5% silver and 7.5%, by mass, of other metals, usually copper.

#### [Bert and Ernie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKfY6kapyBY) -

These numbers relate to the characters' respective favorite numbers, 6 for Bert and 8,243,721 for Ernie. At the end of the video, Ernie states his favorite number after Bert sings his song about the number six.

180 is for 180 degrees, the turn made when you make a half revolution. It matches the u-turn symbol on the hat.

As noted in Bluefeet's answer, 011 is a reference to the character Eleven on *Stranger Things*. She's well known to love Eggo waffles, which explains why this is a waffle-shaped hat and she wears the blue jacket and pink, collared dress that matches the hat, too.

[image: Eleven stealing waffles]
Image from [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/stranger-things-eleven-doesnt-love-waffles-2016-10) article.

Eleven's Tattoo:

[image: Eleven's tattoo]

Comment: That's impressive knowledge of Bert & Ernie esoterica ;-).  Why the leading "0" in `011`?

Comment: @gung I'll leave that to someone who understands it to explain... I personally don't. The others were pretty easy. I only knew the Bert and Ernie ones because I googled 8,243,721 when the hat came out and it turned up the factoid that it was Ernie's favorite number.

Comment: @gung  011 = collect 11 hats