# Why is The Hatter secret hat so named?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

The Hatter secret hat is described below. [Copied from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/333451)

#### The Hatter

[image: The Hatter]

> Post a question at a UTC time that has 00, 15 or 30 as minutes number, i.e. `xx:00:xx`, `xx:15:xx` or `xx:30:xx`. The question must have at least one upvote.

Why is it called The Hatter?

I cannot figure out the relevance of the name. From what I remember, it would make sense if it was granted at 6 PM. Is this 15/30 minute addition to deal with all possible Time Zones (15 minutes for Nepal?). In that case why is there no hat on the 45th minute -- for Nepal?

Comment: Think Alice in Wonderland

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after) is a list of 2016 hats and their 'meaning'. The Hatter isn't there, but it's named after [The Hatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hatter#First_appearances) and it's awarded if it's exactly 6 o'clock *somewhere in the world*.

Comment: @Rathony this isn't ELU, so I don't get why you feel it necessary to say stuff like that. It's rude.

Comment: @Catija The OP asked whether this question belongs on ELU. Did you read that?

Comment: If it is 6PM in Nepal then it is 12:15 UTC ... **you can post at 23:45 only if you are in Nepal** as it is then 6PM UTC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why is the "Hatter"? Because the [Hatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hatter#First_appearances) is:

> In retaliation, time (referred to as a "he" in the novel) halts himself in respect to the Hatter, keeping him and the March Hare stuck at **18:00 (or 6:00 pm)** forever.

You see the words "6:00 pm" there which matches [Glorfindel's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289208/why-is-the-hatter-secret-hat-so-named#comment938749_289208):

> The Hatter isn't there, but it's named after The Hatter and it's awarded if it's exactly **6 o'clock** somewhere in the world.

As @DavidPostill points out:

> If it is 6PM in Nepal then it is 12:15 UTC

There is no place on Earth where xx:45:xx UTC corresponds to 6 PM local, hence only xx:00:xx, xx:15:xx, xx:30:xx UTC are valid times for this hat.

Emphasis is mine.