# What is the logic behind choosing these designs and descriptions of the hats of Winter Bash 2017?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2017

I've wondered what is the logic behind choosing these designs and descriptions for the hats of Winter Bash 2017?

Comment: This question should be edited to look like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after). Will do it myself if/when having time.

Comment: @Stephie heh, if you need to find anything... I can usually help. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I've lost the key to the ice house on my estate in the West Country. Can you help with that too?

Comment: @Bathsheba nah, but I can close this since someone posted a new, better worded,  question. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Since when the oldest question is marked as duplicate? it's the new one who should be marked as duplicate. Plus I've an answer on my post that have +4 and the new question (the one considered by YOU) have an answer with +2. I think that the NEW question should be marked as duplicate not the OLD one. what is this logic? You could suggest  an edit to the oldest question to make it better instead of making it duplicate!

Comment: @ziMtyth question age is not relevant. If the newer question is written better, with more details, etc, better leave it open. I did offer to edit this into shape, see first comment, but since nobody did it, no point doing it now. (What I had in mind is exactly what's written in that newer question.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you could tell me to edit it! I feel like my question was stolen. It's my question, it was me who had the original idea and now I get my question marked as duplicate???!!!! that's not fair. in this situation it would me more correct to tell me to edit it then making it the duplicate because it's my idea man. in the argument of marking my question a duplicate is marked "This question has been asked before and already has an answer" do you thing that's the fact?

Comment: umm... I did tell you to edit, two hours ago. The other question was posted hour ago. And no, it wasn't "your idea", see [this request for same thing in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after). So the author of that can come here and yell "Hey, you stole **my** idea!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Winter Bash is a fun event and as such doesn't require logic.

On a more serious note, you could argue that it encourages participation beyond the usual by introducing an element of [gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) in addition to the system of gaining reputation and badges we already have.

Some hats reflect that by being awarded for maintenance or cleanup tasks, generally things that make the site "better". Others are plain funny, e.g. asking at a certain time.

The names and designs are typically a tongue-in-cheek joke, referring to fictional or real-world figures or events.

In case you noticed that some hats are similar to previous Winter Bashes - why invent the wheel twice? Read the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/) for more information.