# What are the criterias to make a question a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304380/what-is-the-logic-behind-chossing-these-designs-and-descriptions-of-the-hats-of), and then I've got a answer that I considered as the answer to my question. This answer was upvoted by four people. And then my question was considered as a duplicate of [a recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304401/winter-bash-2017-hatymology). The new question has an answer with one upvote.

So my ***oldest*** question was considered as a duplicate of a ***newest*** question on what base?

Comment: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/307988) ...and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/147643?lq=1

Comment: “So my OLDEST question was considered as a duplicate of a NEWEST question on what base?” - Age of a question shouldn’t be a consideration or not if it’s a duplicate of another question

Comment: @Cai the answer to you is in your answer. You say that the question with the more ups and answers must be the one considered as the original. Well, it's my case, my question has more "impact" then the new one.

Answer (score 4):

The other question was better. Sometimes, Closevoters or mods make a judgement call, and they pick the question that's more likely to be a good post for people to find.

In theory we could also have the questions merged, but that needs a mod.

Comment: True, and mods here are SE employees who are usually busy and have better things to do. :)

Answer (score 3):

The concept of a duplicate when it comes to Meta has evolved significantly from its original purpose.

Your (older) question was closed as a duplicate to a newer one since the newer question was felt to be better written and on a sufficiently similar topic, and the duplicate mechanism allows the closed question to be linked to the duplicate target.

The action was also taken by a user with gold tag badge (aka dupe hammer) and seems to me to be in the spirit of preserving the quality of this site.