# Winter Bash 2018 hat names

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Here is a list of the 'etymology' for the [Winter Bash 2018](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) hats. Everything about the naming (whether related to Stack Exchange mechanics, memes or anything else that isn't obvious to most readers) can be found here. For pictures and a list of criteria, see [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838/) instead.

The list is a community wiki; feel free to edit it if you have more information about a hat. Please keep the list in alphabetical order for easier searching. If you like to do some research, some hats have been featured in earlier editions, so you might be able to find more information in the previous installments:

[Winter Bash 2017 hatymology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304401/)
[A list of what each of the Winter Bash 2016 hats are named after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288803/)
[Is there a list of what each of the Winter Bash hats is named after?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270788/) (2015)

Comment: Huh, looked for the wb 2019 naming list and didn't find.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard probably because all hats were reruns.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. This year is awesome, in that regard. So many new hats. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Regular hats

Note that many regular hats were chosen from answers to [this contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304500/295232); the answers might contain explanations about the hat names as well.

- **Freehand circle**: the [only approved way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/295232) to annotate screenshots on Meta sites. During Winter Bash, variations like freehand hats are approved as well.
- **IDENTIFICATION DIVISION** is a reference to [Admiral Grace Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) and [COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasb/iddiv.htm).
- **It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy**: Official slogan of [Chester Cheetah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chester_Cheetah) from 1986 to 1997.
- **Scarf Ace**: a wordplay on the movie [Scarface](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086250/).
- **Still Fresh**: Refers to the trigger; this hat is earned by being a new (or fresh) user on a site.
- **Top(bar) Hat**: both triggers will cause a notification in either the Inbox or the Achievements menu in the top bar.

## Secret hats

> **James Bond**, also known as 007: earned when a question has 0 comments, your answer has 0 comments, and your answer has a score of +7 (or more).
>  **Rubber Ducky**: a reference to the programming technique [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging); also this year's [April Fools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/quack-overflow/info).
>  **Waffles** are a long running meme on the Stack Exchange network. And they are yummy.