# Who should host the annual "Show off your hats" posts?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Starting from 2017, a user hosts a "Show off your hats!" posts for users to, well, show off their hats:

[image]

But I'm a bit confused. Is it that *anyone* can host a Winter Bash's "Show off your hats!" post, as long as they do so before anyone else does? If so, I can see this turning into a competition of "who posts first" in the future if users see this as an easy way to boost their stats.

Comment: And the point of boosting your stats is? This is global meta, what kudos do you think it will get you?

Comment: The user who does it also has to deal with the notifications

Comment: Yes, but don't try to be the first for 2022 Winter Bash by showing off your hat first in January ...

Comment: @RobertLongson Nothing, but you can't argue that there *are* users who care about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posts like these are part of the tradition of this community. Traditions like these come and go; I haven't seen anyone posting the 2021 version of [Winter Bash 2020 hat names & references explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358178/295232) yet. We do already have [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374360/295232) which I personally find a bit early; how do you know your idea for a new hat hasn't been featured this year as a not yet discovered secret hat?

> Is it that *anyone* can host a Winter Bash's "Show off your hats!" post, as long as they do so before anyone else does?

In theory, yes. In practice, I expect that if you post it at a time the community deems it too early, you'll get a lot of downvotes. *When* it's too early may be hard to judge. If you post a placeholder version of [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List 😷 🎓](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372999/295232) I'm pretty sure it will be closed as a duplicate of the 'official' post. (Besides, that's a Community Wiki, so all you get is badges and as @bobble notes, a boatload of notifications.) Other types of these posts might give you reputation, but it might be an idea to make them Community Wiki as well, just like Photography SE did with their [recurring photo competitions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition).

Meta can be [hard to tame at times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/295232) and this is no exception. I fail to predict the community's reaction to certain topics almost daily. I *am* pretty sure that being a well-respected member of this community will increase the chance that a Winter Bash question of yours is well-received, regardless of the actual content of the post. That may be unfair; Stack Exchange should be all about the content, not the user, but it's just how communities tend to work.