# Winter Bash 2021 hats explained

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2021

For carrying on the tradition, here is a list of the 'etymology' for the [Winter Bash 2021](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/) hats. Everything about the naming (whether related to Stack Exchange mechanics, memes, or anything else that isn't obvious to most readers) can be found here. What may be obvious to you (because you're a game expert, or a native English speaker) may not be obvious to other users. For pictures and a list of criteria, see the [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List 😷 🎓](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list) instead.

The list is a community wiki; feel free to edit it if you have more information about a hat. Please keep the list in alphabetical order for easier searching. If you like to do some research, some hats have been featured in earlier editions, so you might be able to find more information in the previous installments:

| Year | Question |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | [Winter Bash 2020 hat names & references explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358178/winter-bash-2020-hat-names-references-explained) |
| 2019 | no entry since all hats were reruns |
| 2018 | [Winter Bash 2018 hat names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319886/) |
| 2017 | [Winter Bash 2017 hatymology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304401/) |
| 2016 | [A list of what each of the Winter Bash 2016 hats are named after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288803/) |
| 2015 | [Is there a list of what each of the Winter Bash hats is named after?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270788/) |

---

<sup>Copied from [Glorfindel's 2020 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358178/winter-bash-2020-hat-names-references-explained).</sup>

Comment: Should we add old hats like Soapbox in the list that were covered in previous posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Regular hats

| Hat | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| [Plus 44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIqWB.png) | Reference to [+44 band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2B44_(band)). |
| [Soapbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llt7q.png) | Reference to the English idiom "to get on a [soapbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapbox)," meaning to publicly make an opinionated speech, analogous to starting a discussion on Meta. |

### Secret hats

> - **[E-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSFKE.png)**: Its trigger is somewhat related to [Gadsby](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsby_(novel)).
> - **[Kitsune](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDSuD.png)**: [Intelligent foxes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune) in Japanese folklore.
> - **[Manual Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whadS.png)**: Stack Overflow ['The Key'](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) prank.
> - **[Matryoshka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88UR.png)**: Reference to [Russian nested dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

Comment: Please post secret hats in a spoiler block.

Comment: Wolgwang why exactly? On [the hat list page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373001/1091571) their names (and images) aren't in spoilers.

Comment: @richardec Because their references can be related to their trigger...