# Winter Bash 2022 hat names explained

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

What follows is a list of the 'etymology' for the [Winter Bash 2022](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) hats. Everything about the naming (whether related to Stack Exchange mechanics, memes, or anything else that isn't obvious to most readers) can be found here. What may be obvious to you (because you're a game expert, or a native English speaker) may not be obvious to other users. For pictures and a list of criteria, see the [Winter / Summer Bash 2022 Hat List ☃️ 🏖️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list) instead.

*Feel free* to edit the answer below if you have more information about a hat. Please keep the list in alphabetical order for easier searching. If you like to do some research, some hats have been featured in earlier editions, so you might be able to find more information in the previous installments:

| Year | Question |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | [Winter Bash 2021 hats explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374649) |
| 2020 | [Winter Bash 2020 hat names & references explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358178) |
| 2019 | no entry since all hats were reruns |
| 2018 | [Winter Bash 2018 hat names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319886) |
| 2017 | [Winter Bash 2017 hatymology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304401) |
| 2016 | [A list of what each of the Winter Bash 2016 hats are named after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288803) |
| 2015 | [Is there a list of what each of the Winter Bash 2015 hats is named after?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270788) |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Winter / Summer Bash 2022 Hat List ☃️ ️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f-%ef%b8%8f)

Comment: @j08691 no. Please retract the close vote. This one is to **explain** the name each hat, not just list it.

Comment: But why can't that all be in the same Q&A?

Comment: @CodyGray too much noise, not everyone are interested in the names explanation so having each in its own place is better, and that's how it is for many years, so can't see any reason to change it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Regular hats

| Hat | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| [11 Will Save The Day](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-40.svg) | A reference to the Demogorgon from the show [Stranger Things](https://www.netflix.com/title/80057281) (with the description also being a reference to a character on the show). |
| [2cool4skool](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-32.svg) | Reference to the idiom ["too cool for school"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=too%20cool%20for%20school). |
| [Hey, Listen!](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-45.svg) | A reference to [the popular Navi meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/navi). |
| [Maverick](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-41.svg) | A reference to the [Top Gun: Maverick](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1745960/) film. |
| [Miranda](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-6.svg) | Hats covered in fruit were popularized by [Carmen Miranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen_Miranda). |
| [Rules lawyer](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-7.svg) | An [English term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_lawyer). |
| [Squared Away](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-47.svg) | [English phrase](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square%20away), meaning "get sorted". |
| [Sufganiyot](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-5.svg) | [A doughnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufganiyah), typically eaten on the Jewish festival Hannukah. |
| [You Got Splunk](https://www.project3851.com/data/wb-hatimg-2.svg) | [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com), the sponsor of Winter Bash 2022 is a company that specializes in data analysis. |

### Secret hats

> - **[Albert Einstein](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/9408417.svg)**: reference to [Albert Einstein's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) hair style.
>
>   **[Emperor's New Hat](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/499755952.svg)**: reference to the famous [The Emperor's New Clothes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes) folktale.
>
>   **[Everything Everywhere All At Once](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/99999927.svg)**: reference to the movie [Everything Everywhere All At Once](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6710474/). The eye on top is a repeated motif of a googly eye. On the bottom is a hands with hot dog fingers. Also imagery used in the movie.
>
>   **[Gregorio Y. Zara](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/4028439.svg)**: the name of a [Filipino engineer and physicist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorio_Y._Zara).
>
>   **[Hedy Lamarr](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/994438.svg)**: the name of an [Austrian-American actress and inventor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedy_Lamarr).
>
>   **[I'm Okay](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/3967443.svg)**: reference to the "This is fine" meme, in which the character Question Hound from the webcomic Gunshow nonchalantly [drinks coffee](http://gunshowcomic.com/648) in the middle of a burning room.
>
>   **[Mario Molina](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ofSe.png)**: the name of a [Mexican chemist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Molina).
>
>   **[Not Found](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/40450021.svg)**: Tribute to the historical Netscape browser broken image icon.
>
>   **[Over 9000!](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/30486924.svg)**: References the [It's Over 9000!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Over_9000!) meme coming from the Dragon Ball Z franchise. The image is of [Super Saiyan hair](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan)
>
>   **[Thomas Mensah](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/5934714.svg)**: the name of a [Ghanian-American chemical engineer and inventor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Mensah_(engineer)).

Comment: Surely 2cool4skool is also a reference to the snowclone 2X4Y (e.g. [2spooky4me](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=2spooky4me))?

Comment: @Laurel surely not surely, but maybe. Only SE staff can confirm or deny, so better stick with the plain explanation for now.

Comment: You Got Splunk doesn't explain why it's the kind of hat it is.

Comment: @Catija is the Slunk hat a hybrid cycling / motorsport crash helmet? Maybe as a reference to others Splunk has sponsored?

Comment: @Rick I'd have thought it's helmet used for [spelunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelunking).

Comment: @VLAZ Yep, you're probably right, but I doubt many outside of the USA would spot the reference.

Comment: @Catija is this actual challenge? How can we know why SE used certain design for their sponsor? Unless there's secret hat as reward, doubt people will go and start researching a third party sponsor to try and find the answer. ;)